# How to dismiss Vuetify v-dialog when clicked outside of it but do it on mousedown event rather than on mouseup?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Is it possible to dismiss `v-dialog` when clicked outside of it, but do it on `mousedown` event? By default, dialog is dismissed when `mouseup` event is generated. To see this here is the [codepen example](https://codepen.io/milost1982/pen/XWrjooN?&editable=true&editors=101).

When you open dialog and then left-click outside of it (on dark overlay) and hold the mouse button down, the dialog is still visible. Only when you release mouse button (`mouseup` event) it will close dialog.

I tried using Vuetify `click:outside` event specified in [v-dialog docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs) but this event doesn't seem to provide additional information as to whether mouse click is `mouseup` or `mousedown`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to do it though dirty hack. Just watch the `dialog` value, and bind and unbind `document.mousedown` listener, that checks if `e.target` is overlay, and if it is closes the dialog.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    dialog(val) {
      if (val) {
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mousedownHandler)
      } else {
        document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.mousedownHandler)
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    mousedownHandler(e) {
      if (e.target.classList.contains('v-overlay__scrim')) this.dialog = false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.7/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.7/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-center">
      <v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="500">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn
            color="red lighten-2"
            dark
            v-on="on"
          >
            Click Me
          </v-btn>
        </template>

        <v-card>
          <v-card-title class="headline grey lighten-2" primary-title>
            Privacy Policy
          </v-card-title>

          <v-card-text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
            in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </v-card-text>

          <v-divider></v-divider>

          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn color="primary" text @click="dialog = false">
              I accept
            </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the most hard and long solution i have ever seen in my life

Comment: according with the current version of vuetify you just need to dismiss "persistent" attribute from <v-dialog> to make it work closing outside